# Laravel 5.1 create not working

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel 5.1. I'm watching a tutorial video and in video teacher is using this code to insert data in database :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\comments;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CommentController  extends Controller
{
    public function getCommentNew()
    {
        $data = array(

            'commenter' => 'soheil' ,
            'comment  ' => 'Test content' ,
            'email'     => 'soheil@gmail.com' ,
            'post_id'   =>  1 ,
        ) ;
        comments::create( $data );
    }


}
```

I am doing the steps  like him but I have a problem , all fields ecept `created_at` and `updated_at` will be empty like this :

[image]

this is my comments model  :

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class comments extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['commenter,email,post_id,comment,approved'];
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\posts');
    }
}
```

and this is  migration :

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedinteger('post_id');
            $table->string('commenter') ;
            $table->string('email') ;
            $table->text('comment') ;
            $table->boolean('approved');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('comments');
    }
}
```

Comment: you fillable attributes should be single element of array, you are setting them all as string in array it should be like this protected $fillable =['commenter','email','post_id','comment,approved'];

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't properly set the `$fillable` attribute in your Model, try with :

```
// in your model
protected $fillable = [
    'commenter','email','post_id','comment','approved'
];
```

Comment: Its nearly the same. But your version is one string, his version is an array with multiple strings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define column names saperately on fillable array as [shempignon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5636688/shempignon) described on above answer
Ex: ['column1', 'column2'...]
not in a single string. Each column name needs to be an array element

Answer (score 1):

Try this and it'll be fine :) , you just forgot `protected $table = 'comments';`

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class comments extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';
    protected $fillable = ['commenter','email','post_id','comment','approved'];
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\posts');
    }
}
```

Comment: this wrong, fillable attributes should be single element of array, you are making string of attributes and putting in array

Comment: pffff I didn't see his code I just added what he missed !!
I'll correct his code right now !
why you put my answer not usefull ???

Comment: @umefarooq undo your action !